# Azure SDK for Go - why are there multiple KeyVault and blob storage clients?

Tags: azure, go, azure-blob-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

In Azure SDK for Go, there are two implementations of KeyVault client,

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/keyvault/azsecrets

and
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/services/keyvault/v7.1/keyvault.

How do I decide between these ?

Similarly, for blob storage, there are multiple clients,

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/services/storage/datalake

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/services/datalake

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/storage/azblob,

again, how do I decide among these options ?

What are the differences among these implementations ?

Answer (score 2):

The different lies in the purpose. There are packages to manage resources and there are packages to interact with the resources.

For example, the management library for azure blob allows you to create and manage storage accounts (management plane). The client library allows you to download and upload blobs (data plane)

See also [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/overview#introducing-the-management-and-client-libraries)

Comment: I understand there are different packages for management of resources and dataplane level tasks, but my point is there exist multiple implementations for dataplane level tasks as well, as I mentioned in the comment of other answer and quoting here in the next comment ...

Comment: """  the Client at location 'sdk/keyvault/azsecret' lets me read secrets from KeyVault, also azsecret is a module so I can use it in my code, and the Client at location 'services/keyvault/v7.1/keyvault' lets me also read the secrets from keyvault, i can use this package by adding module "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go" to my go.mod file, so i can use both of these packages in my code, and they are both dataplane clients, hence my question stands why two different clients for same purpose. """

Answer (score -1):

> In Azure SDK for Go, there are two implementations of KeyVault client,
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/sdk/keyvault
> and
> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/tree/main/services/keyvault.
>
> How do I decide between these ?

You do not have to as neither of them is a Go package you could use ;-)

Its best to read the Go documentation and not the source repo, start here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go

(For the actual difference between the links you gave: see Peter Bons' answer.)

Comment: the Client at location 'sdk/keyvault/azsecret' lets me read secrets from KeyVault, also azsecret is a module so I can use it in my code,
and the Client at location 'services/keyvault/v7.1/keyvault' lets me also read the secrets from keyvault, i can use this package by adding module "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go" to my go.mod file, so i can use both of these packages in my code, and they are both dataplane clients, hence my question stands why two different clients for same purpose.

Comment: @SalmanAzmat I really wold like to recommend that you start by getting the terminology right, e.g. `sdk/keyvault/azsecret` is not a valid package import path.

Comment: here are the full import paths,
"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/keyvault/azsecrets"
"github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/keyvault/v7.1/keyvault"
I just removed the common repo path "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go" for simplicity,